# How to use rancher loadbalancer in internal lab

Tags: docker, rancher

i have several computers in a lab ( in same network ), so, i need to build a ranche-server to all computers use. I already create rancher-server and a host machine, so, the others computers, can acess my rancher typing my ip on the browser, for exemple: `172.16.108.8:8080`. But i need to create a loadbalancer, cuz i will have several services in this rancher.

i created a hello-world node api for tests, and define the request host `test.172.17.0.3.xip.io`. The `172.17.0.3` is the host docker container ip. Local works fine, but if try acess in the another computer, didnt work.. So, how can i configure the loadbalancer to all computers in the lab acess ?